# How to use Azure Pipeline variable in JavaScript (React) project?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

How do I use variable defined for the pipeline in React Project?

Currently, I have build variable defined in the .yml file like that

```
variables:
  src: "virtual-furnace-app"
  dest: "$(src)/build"
  REACT_APP_VERSION: $(Build.BuildNumber)
```

and in the front end code, I have tried to accessing it like that but it is undefined

```
export const REACT_APP_VERSION = process.env.NODE_ENV === "development" ? `v${pjson.version} (Development build)` : `v${pjson.version} (${process.env.REACT_APP_VERSION})` ;
```

Comment: these are never accessible in the front end. unless you send it specifially

Comment: Ok, is there any other way how to get build number in the Azure build displayed in frontend?

Comment: I assume you are serverside rendering. why dont you send the version number along with the HTML

Comment: You can consider setting a variable (e.g. APP_VERSION) in a .env file from your build pipeline. Then in app code load that using `dotenv` package. https://www.twilio.com/blog/working-with-environment-variables-in-node-js-html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After while I found solution myself.

So in the code, I check if we are on localhost `NODE_ENV === development` and if not I will read variable injected to React script `process.env.REACT_APP_VERSION`

```
import pjson from "../../package.json"
export const REACT_APP_VERSION = process.env.NODE_ENV === "development" ? `v${pjson.version} (Development build)` : `v${pjson.version} (${process.env.REACT_APP_VERSION})` ;
```

Azure Pipeline yml code

```
REACT_APP_VERSION=$(BuildID) yarn build
```

Answer (score 0):

> How to use Azure Pipeline variable in JavaScript (React) project?

You could try to use a `.env` file to store the variables, then use them in a React Native app.

You can reference this blog for details : [How to gracefully use Environment Variables in a React Native app](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-gracefully-use-environment-variables-in-a-react-native-app/).

Also find some similar threads in SO, you can reference them can check if that helps:

- [Azure Devops Variable Substitution for Frontend js applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54220775/azure-devops-variable-substitution-for-frontend-js-applications)
- [How to use environment variables in React app hosted in Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51313330/how-to-use-environment-variables-in-react-app-hosted-in-azure)

Besides, you could also try to set `REACT_APP_VERSION` in the start of your script as well, e.g. `"scripts": { "start": "cross-env REACT_APP_VERSION=$REACT_APP_VERSION react-scripts start" }`