# process.env undefined in deployed React app in Azure

Tags: reactjs, webpack, azure-devops, environment-variables, azure-web-app-service

I have a Node app with Express for the Back-end and React for the Front-end.

Locally, I have a .env file where the env variables are located. For Azure App Service, I just save the variables as a configuration so Express can get the env variables. However, React can't see the variables and it's undefined since there is no .env file in Azure DevOps.

I tried the following already:

- Set as REACT_APP_VARIABLE the saved variables for React in the App Service config
- In the Azure Build Pipeline, I've set a build variable and set $env:VARIABLE using PowerShell Task
- Updated webpack to use dotenv-webpack plugin

All the approach didn't work. How do I do this?

Comment: Hi, How about the issue? Does the answer below resolve your question? If yes, you could [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) , so it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a workaround, we could create `.env` file and configure the file content via power shell script.

Steps: set the variable under pipeline Variables page->add task power shell and enter the below script to create `.env` file and set the content.

```
 New-Item -Path $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory) -Name "env.json" -Force -Value @'
 {
  "REACT_APP_SOMW_KEY": "$(REACT_APP_SOMW_KEY)",
 }
 '@
 Get-Content -Path $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\env.json
```

We could also check this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51313330/how-to-use-environment-variables-in-react-app-hosted-in-azure).