# Change Environmet Variables at runtime (React, vite) with docker and nginx

Tags: azure, web-applications, environment-variables, azure-web-app-service, vite

at work I need to make it possible to change the environmet variables at runtime, from an Azure web service, through docker and nginx.
I tried [this](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-implement-runtime-environment-variables-with-create-react-app-docker-and-nginx-7f9d42a91d70/), [this](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2021/03/04/making-environment-variables-accessible-in-front-end-containers#) and some similar solutions, but I couln't get any of them to work.

I also couldn't find any solution online or any article/thread/post that explained if this is even possible, I only always find the text that vite [statically](https://vitejs.dev/guide/env-and-mode.html) replaces the env variables at build time.

During our CI/CD pipeline vite gets the env variables but our Azure admins want to be able to configure them from Azure, just for the case of it.

Does anyone know if this is possible and or maybe has a solution or some help, please ? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

****We Can Change the envirement variable of vite at runtime when running our docker container with nginx Follow the below steps****

**Step-1:** In **.dockerignore** file put your **.env** file so that the environment variables are not get exposed

Let's say you have following variable in **.env** file

```
VITE_API_URL=http://localhost:5000
VITE_KEY=jo2i3jkj3kj
```

**Step-2:** Create a **.env.production** file don't put this file in **.dockerignore** file.

Inside the **.env.production** write your env vars like this it can be prefixed with any characters like here I have prefixed them with **MY_APP_**

```
VITE_API_URL=MY_APP_API_URL
VITE_APP_KEY=MY_APP_KEY
```

We are using a prefix **MY_APP_**

**Step-3:** Create a **env.sh** file in root directory

Inside the **env.sh** file put this code

```
#!/bin/sh
for i in $(env | grep MY_APP_) // Make sure to use the prefix MY_APP_ if you have any other prefix in env.production file varialbe name replace it with MY_APP_
do
    key=$(echo $i | cut -d '=' -f 1)
    value=$(echo $i | cut -d '=' -f 2-)
    echo $key=$value
    # sed All files
    # find /usr/share/nginx/html -type f -exec sed -i "s|${key}|${value}|g" '{}' +

    # sed JS and CSS only
    find /usr/share/nginx/html -type f \( -name '*.js' -o -name '*.css' \) -exec sed -i "s|${key}|${value}|g" '{}' +
done
```

**Step-4:** Create a **Dockerfile** put the following code

```
# Stage 1: Build Image
FROM node:18-alpine as build
RUN apk add git
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build

# Stage 2, use the compiled app, ready for production with Nginx
FROM nginx:1.21.6-alpine
COPY --from=build /app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY /nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY env.sh /docker-entrypoint.d/env.sh
RUN chmod +x /docker-entrypoint.d/env.sh
```

**Step-5:** Run below command to create a docker image

```
docker build -t image-name
```

**Step-6:** To Start the container use the below command to start and add env-vars at runtime

```
docker run --rm -p 3000:80 -e MY_APP_API_URL=api_url -e MY_APP_KEY=key image-name
```

When we run the above command all the env vars which start with prefix **MY_APP_** it will replace the value which we provided using -e flag this is how we can add the env-vars in vite react app at runtime

Hope my solution works in your case
Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

It is `not` possible to dynamically inject `Vite` env variables. But **what is possible**, is to **change the `window object` variables (assign them on runtime).** 
**WARNING!!! DO NOT EXPOSE ANY SENSITIVE VARIABLES THROUGH THE WINDOW OBJECT. YOUR FRONT-END APPLICATION SOURCE IS VISIBLE TO ANYONE USING IT**

**Steps:**

1. Create your desired env files and place them in `<rootDir>/public`. Let's call them `env.js` and `env-prod.js`.
2. Inside your `env.js` and `env-prod.js` You want to assign your desired variables using `var` keyword. Also, you will have to reference these values in your source like `window.MY_VAR` to be able to use them.
3. Create a script tag inside your `<rootDir>/index.html` like this:
   `<script type="text/javascript" src="./env.js"></script>`.
   **IMPORTANT!!!** `type="text/javascript"` is important, because if You specify module, `Vite` will include your `env.js` source inside your minified `index.js` file.
4. Vite config (optional):

```
  plugins: [react(), tsConfigPath()],
  build: {
    emptyOutDir: true, // deletes the dist folder before building
  },
});
```

5. `How to serve the env files on runtime`. Create a `node` server which will serve your frontend application. But before serving the `env.js` file, depending on our `process.env.ENVIRONMENT` you can now choose which env.js to serve. Let's say my node server file is stored at `<rootDir>/server/server.js`:

```
const express = require("express");
const path = require("path");

const app = express();

const env = process.env.ENVIRONMENT || "";

console.log("ENVIRONMENT:", env);

const envFile = path.resolve("public", env ? `env-${env}.js` : "env.js");

const indexFile = path.resolve("dist", "index.html");

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  const url = req.originalUrl;
  if (url.includes("env.js")) {
    console.log("sending", envFile);
    // instead of env.js we send our desired env file
    res.sendFile(envFile);
    return;
  }
  next();
});

app.use(express.static(path.resolve("dist")));
app.get("*", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(indexFile);
});

app.listen(8000);
```

6. Serve your application build while running `node ./server/sever.js` command in your terminal.
7. **Finally:** 
   my `env.js` contains `var RUNTIME_VAR = 'test'`
   my `env-prod.js` contains `var RUNTIME_VAR = 'prod'`
   After I set my `process.env.ENVIRONMENT` to `prod`. I get this file served:
   [image]

Answer (score 5):

My Solution is that it schould work with the links from my question.
I [use this](https://web.archive.org/web/20230223124036/https://pumpingco.de/blog/environment-variables-angular-docker/) approach and it works, the only thing that needs to be thought of is to use a different variable name/prefix (e.g. "APP_...") so vite doesn't change them at build time.
I created a config file wich resolves the variable, for example if the app is in production than it uses the new Variable "APP_.."(which comes injected from nginx/ docker) or use "VITE_..."-variable if "APP_.." is undefined.

Comment: Thanks man! I've been googling this all day and only thanks to you I found the solution.

Answer (score 1):

I came up with a solution and published it as packages to the npm registry.

With this solution, you don't need to change any code:

```
// src/index.js
console.log(`API base URL is: ${import.meta.env.API_BASE_URL}.`);
```

It separate the build step out into two build step:

During production it will be statically replaced `import.meta.env` with a placeholder:

```
// dist/index.js
console.log(
  `API base URL is: ${"__import_meta_env_placeholder__".API_BASE_URL}.`
);
```

You can then run the package's CLI anywhere to replace the placeholders with your environment variables:

```
// dist/index.js
console.log(
  `API base URL is: ${{ API_BASE_URL: "https://httpbin.org" }.API_BASE_URL}.`
);
// > API base URL is: https://httpbin.org.
```

Here is the documentation site: https://iendeavor.github.io/import-meta-env/.

Feel free to provide any feedback.

Answer (score 1):

First create .env file in project root,then define a variable in .env

e.g:`VITE_APP_any = 'any'`

and then add following line to vite.config.js :

```
export default defineConfig(({ command, mode }) => {

  const env = loadEnv(mode, process.cwd(), ""); //this line

  return { 
.
.
.
```

For usage can use following line

`import.meta.env.VITE_APP_any`

Or

`process.env.VITE_APP_any`

Answer (score 1):

I ended up just replacing the variable in js before the container started.

Straight forward, No code changes.

`Dockerfile`

```
FROM nginx:alpine
COPY dist/ /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY docker-entry.sh /docker-entry.sh
RUN chmod +x /docker-entry.sh
EXPOSE 80
ENTRYPOINT ["/docker-entry.sh"]
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

`docker-entry.sh`

```
#!/bin/sh

# replacing Vite's static env vars with injected one
vars=$(printenv | grep '^VITE_' | awk -F= '{print $1}')
find "/usr/share/nginx/html" -type f -name "*.js" | while read file; do
    for var in $vars; do
        echo "Replacing $var in $file"
        sed -i "s/\($var:\"\)[^\"]*\"/\1$(printenv "$var")\"/g" $file
    done
done

exec "$@"
```

Make sure to have template .env when doing `vite build`
else the .js output won't have anything to replace.

Answer (score 0):

here is the **Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:alpine3.14 AS buildJS
WORKDIR /var/www/html
COPY . .
RUN apk add --no-cache yarn \
    && yarn && yarn build

FROM nginx:stable-alpine
WORKDIR /var/www/html
COPY --from=buildJS /var/www/html/dist .
COPY ./docker/conf/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY ./docker/conf/config.json /etc/nginx/templates/config.json.template

ENTRYPOINT []

CMD sleep 5 && mv /etc/nginx/conf.d/config.json config.json & /docker-entrypoint.sh nginx -g 'daemon off;'
```

I'm building the project in the first stage without any envs,
in the second stage I'm copying the files and then creating the **config.json** file based on envs that are passed at run time with ***envstub*** feature of nginx.

then from the project I called the **config.json** file and load the envs from there but be careful you can not import it because imports will be resolved at build time instead you have to get it with **fetch** or **axios** or any equivalents

Answer (score 0):

```
// ./docker-compose.yml
version: '3'
services:
 front:
  /* some params */
  build:
   dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
   context: ./front
  env_file: .env // its important, no need environment

// ./front/Dockerfile - do not use

// ./.env
// https://vitejs.dev/guide/env-and-mode.html
// VITE_* prefix is needed
VITE_SOME_VAR=value 

// ./**/some_script.ts
// Vite + Vue
console.log('expected: ', import.meta.env.VITE_SOME_VAR) // expected: value
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

It's a little late so I am posting this answer for anyone who comes across this question in the future. IMO, the better solution would be similar to what [Jitsi](https://github.com/jitsi/docker-jitsi-meet) uses in their docker images.
The idea is to add a blank `config.js` file in the public folder and add it to `<rootDir>/index.html` as a script (as mentioned in step 3 of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70854230/7866138)).
Now, you can simply create your own `config.js` file and mount it to the running container. This will allow you to change the config whenever you wish to, and not alter any parts of the container that you don't want.

NOTE: User `var` to declare variables so that they are accessible. Also, add the script in a place where it can be included before the main bundle.

Answer (score -2):

You can set the variables in YAML format and update them accordingly as per your requirement.

Below is the sample YAML format which we use as a template:

```
#Set variables once
variables:
  configuration: debug
  platform: x64

steps:

#Use them once
- task: MSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: solution1.sln
    configuration: $(configuration) # Use the variable
    platform: $(platform)

#Use them again
- task: MSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: solution2.sln
    configuration: $(configuration) # Use the variable
    platform: $(platform)
```

Check this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51313330/how-to-use-environment-variables-in-react-app-hosted-in-azure) for more insights to understand environment variables hosted in azure web app

Comment: Thanks for your help but I need to be able to change the env-Variables inside of the Azure App service configuration. We use Gitlab and in there I currently have multiple env-Files for each server(dev, staging, prod), that works fine. But I need to do something like in the linked articles and I don't get that to work.