# Using environment variables in Frontend Vue.js/Vite application that was built into a Docker container (from docker compose)

Tags: docker, docker-compose, vite

I have a dockerized Vue.js/Vite application that needs to talk to a backend API server.
I'm currently using `axios` to perform these requests and depending on whether I'm currently developing locally or deploying onto a production server.

Locally, everything works perfectly – I have a `.env` file that just contains a `API_URL=https://localhost:57100` entry that I then use as axios's base url with `import.meta.env.API_URL`.

However, when building for production and especially using Docker, things are much more hazy to me.
As far as my understanding goes, Vite statically replaces `import.meta.env` statements, so I can't just do stuff like this:

```yaml
environment:
    - API_URL=https://my_production_server.com:57100/
```

because the Vite application is already built and changing the container's environment variables won't do anything anymore.

I've seen approaches [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70854230/3526350) but they seem kinda odd and not very "pretty" to me.
I wondered if there's anything else that I can do or if I'm just looking at the problem from a wrong perspective and there's a better way to do all of this.

If you need the context of the project I'm trying to achieve this for, it [can be found on GitHub](https://github.com/Bassadin/ttn-locator-frontend/tree/7d5947622ab1480a9b72a3fda91e1516c56a1f31).

Comment: Just for documentation, if anyone ever stumbles upon this, I also found this: https://medium.com/@spei/dynamic-runtime-environment-variables-for-dockerized-reactjs-angular-apps-8a78420ec82

It's not much prettier either, though...